# What are the major changes/features in JMeter 4.0? How to upgrade to version 4.0?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, api-testing

JMeter has come up with version 4.0, again this is a major release! Apparently the UX has changed but what are other important changes or features. With the release of 3.0 JMeter came up with the reporting feature and report dashboard. Do we have something for better reporting in this version upgrade as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most detailed description of changes is here:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

To summarize :

- Boundary extractor for easy data extraction and correlation
- JSON Assertion
- Precise Throughput Timer
- Custom messages in assertions
- Java 9 Compatibility
- 5 new functions, some for digest and hashing

In few nymbers:

- 76 enhancements
- 24 bug fixes